# Count child matches in linq Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I try to count the number of child elements for each parent where the parent id is in a list if ints. But the count is not correct. Is it not possible to make a query like this? What is the correct way of doing this?

```
List<int> ids = [1, 2, 3];
var counts = (from d in db.Parent where ids.Contains(d.Id) select d.Child.Count()).ToList();
```

Comment: After your edit: this still isn't clear. The query seems to do exactly what you want, esp. after seeing your comment on the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query does exact what I want, sorry for that. My problem was that the ids list was not sorted and that somehow made the query to not sort the output as the ids list was sorted. By sort the ids list (ids.Orderby(id)) this question was solved.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming Child is a collection, because you are attempting to count it.
Try the following:
`var counts = db.Parent.Where(x => ids.Contains(x.Id)).SelectMany(x => x.Child).Count();`

"Count" will work on an IEnumerable. However it seems you are trying to work with a collection of IEnumerables. In these situations use "SelectMany" so that all the resulting collections are joined into one single collection.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to count the individual number of child elements so I end up with a list of intergers with the count of the number of child elements of each parent. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: You mean you want a collection with parent ids related with the count of childs for each one if them. Like a collection of key-value pairs. Is that it?

Answer (score 0):

A list of counts and nothing else may offer sufficient information, but often some information on the containing entity will be useful (if only to prevent confusion):

```
List<int> ids = [1, 2, 3];
var counts = (from d in db.Parent where ids.Contains(d.Id) 
              select new
              {
                  Parent = d.Name,
                  ChildCount = d.Child.Count()
              }).ToList();
```